# how to dynamically generate page numbers and only load the corresponding page in the grid?

Tags: asp.net

I need to load data in the gridview dynamically. That is when the user clicks the page number 2 then those records only has to be displayed.. I made a stored proc to return only those records whose page number is sent.. It will also return me the number of records too.. Now i want to create a placeholder which will create the page number buttons dynamically based on the number of records. Could anyone help me with the placeholder code.. ??

Answer (score 1):

You need to use ObjectDataSource for custom paging in GridView.

Check these articles:

https://web.archive.org/web/20210510021915/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/031506-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you love AJAX, give this a try:
http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ajax/ASPNETAjaxGridAndPager.aspx

Quote from the page:

> Paging
>
> When working with large tables we
>   often required to use paging. Although
>   the DataGrid/GridView has built-in
>   support for paging they are pretty
>   much useless. Most developers often
>   refuse to use the built-in
>   functionality and use their own custom
>   logic which usually takes a start
>   index, page size and other additional
>   parameters and in turn returns only
>   the paged records with the total
>   number of records.

There are enough codes on the page to help you start the balll rolling.

Comment: Someone needs to tell dotnetslackers.com that they are slacking. The link goes to a server error page with something about their web config file. Would you have more information about the content of the link? I was interested to see your solution.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to use DataGrid instead. DataGrid has paging property